# Read iD3 bit rate tag of files and write it to folder name (folder containing the files)

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, mp3, directory, id3

In in the middle of my first serious attempt to consolidate a huge music library with nearly 20.000 folders (every album is a folder). Folders are named like:

**Artist - Year - Album Name**

But as with any huge library, there are many album duplicates, and I've found more and more duplicates as I set all folder naming to the naming standard mentioned above.

To resolve the album duplicates, I've decided to keep the one with the highest possible bitrate, by naming the folders like so:

**Artist - Year - Album Name [*bitrate* kbps]**

That way I can easily see which folder I'll keep and delete all the low quality ones. But this task is proving to be too time-consuming.

So I'm wondering if that can be done through OSX Terminal. The solution would look like this:

1. Find iD3 "bit rate" tag of files within the folder
2. Write the found bit rate tag at the end of the folder name, like

**Artist - Year - Album Name [*320* kbps]**

If the bitrate for the files within the folder are different from each other, set name to

**Artist - Year - Album Name [*vrb* kbps]**

*Note that I'd like to do it **locally** in my machine, using the Terminal or any other tool available. No server involved or scripting language involved...*.

Any help in any direction would be awesome! Bear in mind that I'm not an advanced Terminal user, so I'd really appreciate a baby-step explanation... ;)

Comment: What have you tried? What tools are available on your system? (How) should we deal with corner cases like folders with files with different bitrates?

Comment: I haven't tried anything through Terminal, I'm too inexperienced to even start there. My system is OSX Lion, and I've been renaming folders using the Better Rename 9 app. It lets me do stuff with some of the iD3 tags, but not the bit rate tag. I'm just assuming something on that line should be possible through Terminal... Folders with files with different bitrates could be either skipped or get a "vbr" (variable bit rate) instead of the shared bit rate in most folders.

Comment: @tripleee - For reference, [this forum question](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-do-i-rename-a-music-folder-so-as-to-indicate-the-bitrate-in-its-name-878600/) is the closest thing to what I intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/04/check-bitrate-of-mp3-and-audio-files/ try something like

```
find /path -type d |
while read folder; do
    prev=
    br=
    for file in "$folder"/*; do
        case $file in "$folder/*") break;; esac  # Skip empty directories
        br=$(afinfo "$file" | awk '/Bit rate:/{print $3/1000}')
        echo '##' "$br" "$file"
        case $prev in "" | $br) prev=$br; continue;; esac
        br="vbr"
        break
    done
    case $br in '') continue;; esac  # Don't rename if we don't have a bitrate
    echo moving "$folder" to "$folder [$br]"
    mv "$folder" "$folder [$br]"
done
```

Untested; maybe try this without the rename first.  Take out the `echo` lines if you prefer silent operation.

Comment: your answer seems to make sense, but what part should I change to make it work on my machine (path, etc.)? I use terminal very seldom for local stuff.

Comment: `/path` is a placeholder for the directory containing all the directories you want to process.

Comment: I changed the first line to `find /Volumes/OWC\ Mercury\ Elite-AL\ Pro\ Qx2/__music__/test -type d |` (got the path by dragging the folder into Terminal). I created a file `get_bit_rate.sh`, navigated to the folder through Terminal and ran it. I did run, but there came the same error for all folders: `fail: AudioFileOpenURL failed for 'folder/*'`.

Comment: Sorry for the error, sloppy editing. Fixed now - I had `for file in folder/*` where obviously I meant `for file in "$folder"/*`

Comment: This is the output I get, simplified: `1st line: fail: AudioFileOpenURL failed for '/path/album-name/*'` then `2nd line: ##  /path/album-name/*` then `3rd line: moving /path/album-name to /path/album-name []` then `mv: rename /path/album-name to /path/album-name []: No such file or directory`. Cheers for all the help so far, btw!

Comment: My last comment shows the output for one folder... Another thing worth mentioning is that the parent folder (the one that contains all the other folders and is mentioned on my second comment gets a ' []' by the end of its name, becoming 'test []'.

Comment: The error looks like `/path/album-name` is an empty directory.  I've added a special case for empty directories.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I get the same error on _every_ folder within the parent folder (here represented as `/path/`). The parent folder is the only one that gets the ' []' at the end of its name. All children folders have mp3s in them. I've also tried to run the script on one of the album folders, just to try, but got only a ' []' at the end of that folder as well.